# @syncfusion/ej2-angular-calendars datepicker getting previous values when using with reactive forms

Tags: angular, syncfusion, angular8, ej2-angular-calendars

In my `angular 8` app, I am using `@syncfusion/ej2-angular-calendars` for showing calendar.

my html is like

```
<form [formGroup]="visitsForm">
    <div class="disp-in-b mr-bt-sm">
        <ejs-datepicker #ejDatePicker formControlName="visitDate" [value] = "" name="visitDate" id='datepicker' placeholder="{{ 'general.selDate' | translate }}" format="dd/MM/yyyy" (change)="filterVisits()"></ejs-datepicker>
    </div>
    <div class="disp-in-b inline-checkbox text-center float-right" formGroupName="visitType" (change)="filterVisits()">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" value="" id="appointments" formControlName="appointments">
               {{ 'general.appointments' | translate }}
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" value="" id="consultation" formControlName="consultation">
             {{ 'general.consultation' | translate }}
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" value="" id="tokens" formControlName="tokens">
            {{ 'general.tokens' | translate }}
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

And in my component file, I have the below function

```
filterVisits() {
    const formVals = this.visitsForm.value;
    console.log(this.visitsForm.value);
}
```

I am getting the value of the date filed as `null` at the first date change. Then if I change the date again, I am getting the previously selected date but not the current selected date. But the `change` in the check boxes are working fine.

I selected date "21/08/2019" and the value in `this.form.value` is like

```
{
    visitDate: ""
    visitType: {appointments: "", consultation: "", tokens: ""}
    __proto__: Object
}
```

Then I selected the date "10/08/2019" and the value in `this.form.value` is like

```
{
    visitDate: Wed Aug 21 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
    visitType: {appointments: "", consultation: "", tokens: ""}
    __proto__: Object
}
```

**It is supposed to show the date 10/08/2019 instead of 21/08/2019**.

What am I doing wrong here? Please help to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion form component values are after change event has been raised. So, you can take the value from formObject in change event, then you can get the previous value. For this scenario, you can get the updated value in form object using blur event. Please refer the below sample.

Sample link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-krvj7d?file=app.component.ts.